# Spring Boot URL Length Validation

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

For security reasons, I need to return a `400` error if the URI request length is greater than `1024` characters in length.

Is there a way to test this in Spring Boot?

Currently I have a simple Controller doing validation on the query string and header params

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class myController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = GET)
    public SegmentationResponse getSegments(
            @PathVariable("id") @Valid @Size(min = 12) String id,
            @RequestHeader(value = "X-API-Key", required = true) @ValidAPIKey String apiKeyHeader,
            @RequestParam(value = "myParam", required = true) @Valid @Pattern(regexp = MY_REGEX) String myParam) {

        // DO Stuff
    }
}
```

**Desired**

`http://localhost:8080/<More than 1024 chars here>`

Returns `400 Bad Request`

Comment: Seems like something for a filter and not a controller.